# ios- Does your app contain, display, or access third-party content? Cocoapods

Tags: ios

Do cocoa pods like google maps, tpkeyboardavoiding, and charts also come under the third party content?
What do I need to answer “yes” or “no” in such a case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, they want to know if you are using images or text that belongs to another copyright holder. These pods are not content in that way, and you have permission to use in your App in any case.